# Empty array returned when executing stored procedure against MSSQL server

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I am trying to execute a stored procedure against a local MSSQL server but I am getting an empty array as catched by the `catch` block although when executed in `SSMS` I get one record returned.

**The error I get**

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
> at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.MaxInteger[T](IEnumerable1 source)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
> at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitBlockExpressions(ExpressionVisitor visitor, BlockExpression block)
> at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBlock(BlockExpression node)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, IReadOnlyList 1& readerColumns, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<c__DisplayClass12_01.<ExecuteAsyncb__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func1 compiler)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Project.Infrastructure.Repositories.SupplierDashboardRepository.GetORdersListAsync(String externalUID) in
> C:.path\Project.Infrastructure\Repositories\SupplierDashboardRepository.cs:line
> at Project.Application.Services.Supplier.Analytics.SupplierDashboardService.GetSubscriptionsListAsync(String externalUID) in C:.path\Project.Aplication\Services\Supplier\Analytics\SupplierDashboardService.cs:line 55
> at Project.WebApi.Controllers.Supplier.Dashboard.General.SubscriptionController.GetSubscriptionsListAsync(String externalUID) in C:.path\Project\Controllers\Supplier\Dashboard\General\SubscriptionController.cs:line 31
> at lambda_method5(Closure, Object)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsyncg__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsyncg__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsyncg__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsyncg__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsyncg__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invokeg__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>
> HEADERS Accept: text/plain Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-US,en Connection: close Host: localhost:44385
> Referer: https://localhost:44385/swagger/index.html User-Agent:
> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
> like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 sec-ch-ua:
> "Chromium";v="118", "Brave";v="118", "Not=A?Brand";v="99"
> sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0 sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows" sec-gpc: 1
> sec-fetch-site: same-origin sec-fetch-mode: cors sec-fetch-dest: empty

This is my method within the `repository`:

```
public class AnalyticsRepository : IAnalyticsRepository
{
    public AnalyticsRepository(GuacamoleContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<AnalyticsOrder>> GetOrderListAsync(string externalUID)
    {
        try
        {
            var OrderList = await Context.AnalyticsOrders.FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC usp__OrderList @externalUID = {externalUID}").ToListAsync();

            return OrderList;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error {e.Message}");
            return new List<AnalyticsOrder>();
        }
    }

    public GuacamoleContext Context { get; }

}
```

This is my method within the `service`:

```
public class SupplierAnalyticsService : ISupplierAnalyticsService
{
    private readonly ISupplierAnalyticsRepository _supplierAnalyticsRepository;

    public SupplierAnalyticsService(ISupplierAnalyticsRepository supplierAnalyticsRepository)
    {
        _supplierAnalyticsRepository = supplierAnalyticsRepository;
    }


    public async Task<List<AnalyticsOrder>> GetOrdersListAsync(string externalUID)
    {
        return await _supplierAnalyticsRepository.GetOrderListAsync(externalUID);
    }
}
```

This is my `controller`:

```
   public class OrdersListController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ISupplierAnalyticsService _supplierAnalyticsService;

        public OrdersListController(ISupplierAnalyticsService supplierAnalyticsService)
        {
            _supplierAnalyticsService = supplierAnalyticsService;
        }

        [HttpGet("analytics/orders/list")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status413PayloadTooLarge)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<AnalyticsOrder>>> GetOrdersListAsync(string externalUID)
        {
            var list = await _supplierAnalyticsService.GetOrdersListAsync(externalUID);

            return Ok(list);
        }
```

In the DbContext, I've added a new entity and set it not to have a key as per Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=fluent-api):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AnalyticsOrder>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

What am I missing here? Why am I getting an empty array when execute the `stored procedure` via Swagger? Thanks

Comment: What was the error message (that was output to the console)? Your procedure definition would be useful.

Comment: @Charlieface - edited my question

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToView(null)`

Comment: Thought I need to specify the structure i'm expecting back. Point is without calling `ToView` returns the same error message.

Comment: What happens if you try loading this entity from the table directly? If the entity does not represent a table but the results of this custom stored proc, then you might try creating a view. The issue is most likely related to details in the entity definition and/or the stored procedure itself where EF is trying to translate a result but is encountering an impass which what it gets and what it expects.

Comment: Is the stored proc inserting or updating other table/s before it returns its results? If so then does it include `SET NOCOUNT ON;` as its first statement?

Comment: To be honest, this looks like a bug in EF Core (that exception should never have been thrown). Exactly what's going wrong is unclear. I suggest you post this on their GitHub site as an issue, with a full [mcve]

Comment: I would have gone for a `view` @StevePy but I need it parameterized.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - just a `select`, that's it.

Comment: @Charlieface ok, will open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Maybe use an inline Table Valued Function and then `SELECT * FROM dbo.YourFunction({param})`

Comment: @Charlieface - manage to overpass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, after some time, came across and found the solution.

Initially, I set in the `DbContext` the entity as it follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Type>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

What's wrong here? Nothing, UNLESS you want to map it to a `view`. To map the `entity` to a `stored procedure` you need to use `.HasNoKey().ToFunction("[dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName]")`.

Moving further, `EF Core` was creating a table with every migration although I specifically set it to have no key. To overpass it, I've set in the `DbContext` to be excluded from the migrations. The complete code line is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<YourType>().HasNoKey().ToFunction("[dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName]").Metadata.SetIsTableExcludedFromMigrations(true);
```

Last but not least, the return type **MUST** have class props. So, define the model properly:

```
public class Model
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    ....................................
}
```

And to make sure that `EF Core` fully understands, I also included the fully qualified name of the `stored procedure` when call it from the method:

```
public async Task<List<Type>> GetListAsync(string externalUID)
    {
        try
        {
            var xList = await Context.DbSetType
                .FromSqlInterpolated($"EXEC [dbo].[YourStoredProcedureName] @externalUID = {externalUID}")
                .ToListAsync();

            return xList;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error {e.Message}");
            return new List<Type>();
        }
}
```

I hope that this solution would save you some time!